# Webpack suppress messages per module/rule

Tags: webpack, webpack-2

Is there a way to suppress messages/warning/errors for a certain module or rule in Webpack?

Let's say I am using a regex to get SVG images like so:

```
test: /\.svg$/
```

Is there a way to suppress these messages?

[image]

Comment: I see there are couple of links around that but don't know which one would be useful to you exactly https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/476 https://webpack.js.org/configuration/stats/#stats https://github.com/webpack/webpack-dev-server/issues/68 https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/1191

Comment: @sandyJoshi I'm gonna check them out, will let you know if one works.